# How to set up vnc server?

Tags: 10.10, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access

I want to set up a vncserver on my machine. I need each remote user to start separate session - so they see the login screen after connecting, log in, and so on - without interrupting another users.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VNC Server does not show you the login screen - instead it takes you straight to the desktop, after you have logged in. If your goal is make sure that the users can log in remotely with a GUI without interrupting the other users who are already logged in, here is what you need to do.

First, install vnc onto your machine.

```
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

For each user, you can make them set a vnc password

```
vncpasswd
```

that asks for a password. Afterwards, each user can log in remotely (via the command line) and set up their own VNC server:

```
vncserver
```

This will output something like

> New 'machine:1 (user)' desktop is machine:1
>
> Creating default startup script /home/user/.vnc/xstartup
>   Starting applications specified in /home/user/.vnc/xstartup
>   Log file is /home/user/.vnc/machine:1.log

Once this is done, each user can log in to the GUI of their respective accounts using your machine's ip address and the desktop session number. In the above example, if the IP address of the machine is 10.0.0.1 then you can can put `10.0.0.1:1` as the server to connect to in the VNC client.

Comment: The problem is, that I saw exactly what I described - user just typed "vncviewer host" and got a full login screen. The problem is that admin in that place was not very helpful - he failed to describe how it works, seems he just forgot.

Comment: Possibly the `vncpasswd` would work then instead of the regular password? Or did the above solve your problem?

Comment: Actually, this thread *nearly* solved my problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=122402 But it does not work on 10.10 - gdm login greeter hangs :( It seems to be fixed in 11.04, though.